# Nuxt vuex state menuList:undefined in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

guy. I'm novice programmer.

I have question for nuxt use vuex get data for api.

so data call in vue value null but in dev tool vue has data.

How to use getters in nuxt.

This image from dev tool.
[image]

In getters and state chachange: menuList has array data but in component not data.

This image from component
[image]

Component MenuList> computed> menuList: undefined.

This my menu_list.vue code.

```
computed: {
    menuList () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      return this.$store.getters.getMenuList
    }
  },
  beforeCreated () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(this.$store.state)
    this.$store.dispatch('chachang/fetchMenu')
  },
  created () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(this.$store.state)
    this.$store.dispatch('chachang/fetchMenu')
  }
```

This vuex code.
Chachang/state.js

```
export default () => ({
  menuList: []
})
```

Chachang/actions.js

```
export default {
  async fetchMenu ({ commit }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.get('https://hlkittipan.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/menu.json')
    commit('SET_MENU', response.data)
  }
}
```

Chachang/mutations.js

```
export default {
  SET_MENU (state, menu) {
    state.menuList = menu
  }
}
```

Chachang/getters.js

```
export default {
  getMenuList: (state) => {
    return state.menuList
  }
}
```

This store/index.js

```
import chachangActions from './chachang/actions'
import chachangStates from './chachang/state'
import chachangGetters from './chachang/getters'
import chachangMutations from './chachang/mutations'

export const state = () => ({
  ...chachangStates.state,
})

export const mutations = {
  ...chachangMutations.mutations, 
}

export const actions = {
  ...chachangActions.actions
}

export const getters = {
  ...chachangGetters.getters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  async beforeMount () {
        const data = await this.$store.dispatch('chachang/fetchMenu')
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(data)
      },computed: {
        menuList () {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          return this.$store.getters['chachang/getMenuList']
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

I will advice you to use mapActions and mapGetters that are imported from vuex.

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

```
export default{
...
   methods:{
      ...mapActions('chachang',[ 'fetchMenu' ])
   },
   mounted(){
      this.fetchMenu() // better to use fetchData instead 
   }
   computed:{
      ...mapGetters('chachang', [ 'menuList' ])
   }

..
}
```

Comment: Hi, Levy_from_Odessa it can work But I think it is not correct for my problem solving.